# rails: User Net::Http post json to reply review google app develop api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to reply a review from google app.

This is link document: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/reviews/reply

I use Net::HTTP to post data.

my method to reply review

```
def self.reply_review(package , access_token, review_id, text )

    uri = URI("https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/#{package}/reviews/#{review_id}:reply?access_token=#{access_token}")
    puts "https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/#{package}/reviews/#{review_id}:reply?access_token=#{access_token}"
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    params = {
      "replyText" => text
    }
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(
      uri.request_uri, 
      'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    )
    request.body = params.to_json
    response = http.request(request)
    puts response
    puts(response.body)
    response
  end
```

but it always response

```
 =>  => #<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true>
```

I am sure my data into accurate (packageName, access_token, replyId).
And how to fix this to reply a review use Net::HTTP

Comment: Have you added `require 'net/http'`?

Comment: yes, i have added `require 'net/http'`

Answer (score 0):

I have used this to connect with google Verification API.

```
require 'openssl'
require 'net/http'

uri =URI.parse("https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/#{package}/reviews/#{review_id}:reply?access_token=#{access_token}")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri,
                  initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})
request.form_data = {"replyText" => text}
response = http.request(request)
```

Comment: same error above: ` #<Net::HTTPNotFound 404 Not Found readbody=true> 
`

Comment: In the documentation the URL ends with `reply`, but in your code it ends with `reply_review`.

Comment: thanks, i edit question above.
t try edit url but don't work, error: ` => #<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true> `
i run: `Serverkits::GoogleApi::GoogleDevelop.reply_review(Database.first.package, User.first.google_access_token, Database.first.reviews.first.id, "text")`

Comment: Are you geting 404 or 400? If you are getting 400 then the format in which the data is sent is not correct, if it is 404 then the url does not exist. Can you also try to make the request now from the code which I have provided above?

Comment: by google doc: `400 Bad Reply Request
The replyText is too long or is missing.`
but replyText = "text", it so short

Comment: Is the replyText too long?